# Integrate Raphael js to OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, raphael, openlayers-3

I need to integrate **Raphael js svg** into **OpenLayers3 map**. But inserted svg need change size then user change scale in map.
Thanks.

Comment: Which approach have you taken to integrate the SVG? `ol.source.ImageStatic`? `ol.source.ImageCanvas`? If you want this question answered, you'll need to provide more context. Preferably a working code snippet.

Comment: Need of Raphael library dynamically drawing in map (in new layer) svg image with the ability to intercept events (clicks, drag and drop, keystrokes). In all, object of raphael must repeat the behavior layer svg if it was created directly in openlayers. I decided this task by means of ol3 , but unfortunately opportunities of ol3 by drawing svg restricts for me. I must know how to create OL3 svg layer and pass in it the Raphael. And after, may possible re-paint svg image by raphael.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to use SVG in an OpenLayers 3 layer is to have an image element with content-type `image/svg+xml`. This can be used directly through `ol.source.ImageStatic`, or manually by creating a canvas and adding the SVG image to it using `CanvasContext2D#drawImage()` with an `ol.source.ImageCanvas`. In both cases, you will not have access to the DOM of the SVG, and lose any animations or interactivity inside the SVG. Also, to create that image element, you'll need to base64 encod­e the serialized SVG document and cre­at­e a data URI whenever you change the SVG. I guess this is not what you are looking for.

Another approach would be to use an `ol.Overlay`. This will anchor your SVG to a coordinate on the map. You'll have to scale and rotate the SVG manually to match the resolution and rotation of the map's view (shouldn't be too hard), but you can fully interact with the SVG's DOM.

Comment: @ahocevar. can you maybe supply a working example on the most performant way to add an svg graphic to openlayers? Maybe with the newer version this can be done more easily? I'm stuggling with this at the moment and there seem to be a lot of unanswered questions on stack about this..